# 'android.support.design.widget' cannot be safely rewritten. How to fix this?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I get this error while **building** the project :-

> The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference
> 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten.
> Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be
> updated manually to add support for androidx.

I have also **cleaned the project** many times. I tried many solutions but nothing worked for me...

My **gradle.properties** :-

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

*(I have removed the comments of the gradle.properties file)*

My **build.gradle(:app)** :-

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
    id 'com.android.application'
    // Other plugins here if pre-existing
}

android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true}
    compileSdk 32

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dccodes.chugli"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 5
        versionName '1.0'

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    namespace 'com.dccodes.chugli'
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
//    implementation 'androidx.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji:1.1.0'
   
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:android-otpview-pinview:2.1.2'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.github.pgreze:android-reactions:1.6'
    implementation 'com.devlomi:circularstatusview:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.OMARIHAMZA:StoryView:1.0.2-alpha'
    implementation 'com.github.sharish:ShimmerRecyclerView:v1.3'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.8.2'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.24'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My **build.gradle(Chugli)** :-

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I don't understand why I get this error....
**Please can anyone help me?**

Answer (score 1):

To solve this error, **remove this line** :-

```
//implementation 'androidx.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

and **add this line** to your **build.gradle(:app)** :-

```
implementation 'androidx.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```